# When looping over shapes in a document I get only Comment types even though it has many drop down menues

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, vba

I have a file that someone made and I was tasked with simply adding an autoupdater function that updates the cell next to the dropdown menu.

The way the dropdown menu is created is by going to data validation and selecting list and make list in cell. The values are read from elsewhere.

Now, what I tried was to loop over all shapes like this:

```
Dim dd As DropDown
Dim i As Integer
Debug.Print Sheet1.DropDowns.Count
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Dim s As Shape
        For Each s In ws.Shapes
            Debug.Print CStr(s.Type)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

This prints the following:[4 is a comment, 8 is a control form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860759.aspx)

```
444444444444444444444444444
8
```

So even though I have many drop down menus none come out when I loop over them.

I wanted to make it so that anyone can add a dropdown box and my code would attach an OnAction Sub that fills in the cell next to the dropdown box so the user can add as many boxes they want, but they have to only remember to keep the cell next to it, to the right for example, empty as it will be overridden.

```
Dim sh As Shape
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each sh In ws.Shapes
        If sh.Type = msoFormControl Then
            If sh.FormControlType = xlListBox Then
                sh.OLEFormat.Object.OnAction = "UpdateLBCell"
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

The original code above causes an object error on the innermost line.

Am I just stupid or is it not possible to loop over these dropdown boxes?
If it is impossible, can I make some other dropdown single select boxes that fit inside a cell? Combobox I tried, but they lie on top and dont match.

Any insight in alternative ways to do this is very appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put a list validation on a few cells, then ran this code

```
Sub Test()

    Dim dd As DropDown
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Dim s As Shape
        For Each s In ws.Shapes
            Debug.Print CStr(s.Type), s.Top, s.Left
            s.Visible = msoCTrue '<<<<
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Before and after (yellow cells have data validation):

[image]

So it seems as though if you have a "list" data validation set up, Excel manages a single (normally invisible and empty) drop-down which is typically positioned at the current active cell.  It's only made visible when that's also one of the cells with validation set up.

**EDIT**: here's an example of how you could handle updates to cells with drop-down DV lists in a generic way -

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range

    On Error GoTo haveError

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each c In Target.Cells
        If HasDVList(c) Then
            c.Offset(0, 1) = Now
        End If
    Next c

haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

'does a cell have DV list?
Function HasDVList(rng As Range)
    Dim v
    On Error Resume Next
    v = rng.Cells(1).Validation.Type
    On Error GoTo 0
    HasDVList = (v = 3)
End Function
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Does this mean that they are all copies of one another? So that I get only one because they are all identical lists? I ran your code and I got this output [8 0 96]. The other way I can understand your answer is that it does not loop through the entire document, only the one selected. If so it is useless. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Yes - no matter how many different lists you set up, there's only a single drop-down used to handle all of them: normally it's empty and invisible, and it's made visible when you select a cell with DV (?and then filled when you click the down arrow to show the options?)

Comment: Then how can I then achieve this? It seems impossible to do it this way then. Can I make in-cell drop down list from code? I have managed to put on on top, but I need to give the user an easy way to add these drop down boxes. I could give them an array of coordinates to add to and then simply set the .onaction for each.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would allow the user to add their own drop-downs: there would need to be some way for your code to know when to create/move a list and what the list contents should be.  You might be better off tracking the `Change` event, and updating the adjacent cell when the `Target` range has a validation list applied to it.

Comment: If I could tap in to the global change event that would be great. I could then call a function next to where the change event was called. I presume you refer to the SheetChange event? I will try. Thanks.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)  If Target.Value = "Test" Then. This is always true so I am unable to control what I do next. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

The `Shape` should be `Visible`, whether the cell is "clicked-on" or not.  I put a single DV dropdown on a sheet and ran:

```
Sub ShapeLister()    
    Dim s As Shape
    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        MsgBox s.Type & vbCrLf & s.Name
    Next s
End Sub
```

and got:

[image]

Try this on a fresh worksheet and tell us what you see.

Comment: I selected 6 cells and Di the following: Data->Data Validation-> Set as follows: http://puu.sh/r4D29/af944792e4.png  Then, when I ran your code and got this: http://puu.sh/r4D4R/923bd636c1.png